# How can I work on aws regions in a while list in Bash

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, do-while

I am using this code to get my AWS region. I want working on them in a while loop.

```
awsRegionList=$(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r '.Regions[] | .RegionName')
while [I can't find the expression work with my variable]:
do
     echo " working on : (I want here the regionName)"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash you need to use a `for` loop to iterate over a list, instead of a `while` loop:

```
awsRegionList=$(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r '.Regions[] | .RegionName')
for region in $awsRegionList
do
     echo " working on : ${region}"
done
```